# jQuery image (product) slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to figure this out, but it seems a bit hard. I have a list of images (inside a `<li>`) with a few products (10).. However, what I want, is the image to slide from left to right showing the images as they slide over (non-stop) and when the last image is displayed, the first one would be displayed again. So, there would never be a gap/pause of images just slider over the 10 products all the time..

Is there any tutorials on this? or any plugins I can look at?

NOTE: i don't want a slider with "arrows" and, "next" buttons, this should happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[Basic jQuery slider](http://www.basic-slider.com/) provides that. Autoslide, animation effects, configuration.